# Nested mongo query

Tags: mongodb

Here is what the data looks like:

```
{
    "_id" : {
            "item" : "1",
            "state" : "something"
    },
    "things" : {
            "ordered" : 2,
            "cost" : 123
    }
}
```

I try to query for all doc of item 1, there are many state for that item. I know i can get that record using `db.orders.find({_id:{item:"1", state: "something"}})`. But I would like to get all states I try something like `db.orders.find({_id:{item:"1", state: {$exists: true}}})`

But that doesn't seem to work. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the list of all the different states you could use.

```
db.orders.distinct("_id.state");
```

If you want to get the list of all the states in your collection

```
db.orders.find({}, {"_id.state": 1});
```

> I really want to get the things.cost for all the states for a given
>   item

```
db.orders.aggregate([
    { $group : { 
           _id : { item : "$_id.item" , state : "$_id.state"}, 
            cost: { $push :  "$things.cost"  }
           }
    }
]);
```

If you want the sum instead of the elements of the group by use `$sum` instead of `$push`

> How do i get for certain item?

```
db.orders.aggregate([
    { $match : { "_id.item" : "YOUR_ID" }},
    { $group : { 
           _id : { item : "$_id.item" , state : "$_id.state"}, 
            cost: { $push :  "$things.cost"  }
           }
    }
]);
```

Comment: I really want to get the `things.cost` for all the `states` for a given `item`

Comment: you need to use aggregation to to do that, I will update my answer

Comment: Awesome thank you. How do i get for certain item? i tried changing `"$_id.item"` for my item number `"1"`, but that didn't work.

Comment: I add an example , you need to use $match, just remember to replace YOUR_ID with the item number